# Can't get data from server with captcha on android device

Tags: android, cookies, captcha

I'm trying to get data from http://www.gibdd.ru/proxy/check/fines/2.0/client.php, but server responds that captcha is incorrect or expired. In advanced rest client into chrome request work's perfect. My alghoritm to getting data is:

1. Get session from http://www.gibdd.ru/proxy/check/getSession.php
2. Get captcha with session id `http://www.gibdd.ru/proxy/check/getCaptcha.php?PHPSESSID=te67jgdiv53v956fcv8rk9mg81`
3. And then send form data to `http://www.gibdd.ru/proxy/check/fines/2.0/client.php`

I think my problem with cookies, i set cookies = sessionId, like rest client, but something gone wrong

UPD: I'm using retrofit to server requests
That API class

```
private static final String URL= "http://www.gibdd.ru";
private static RestAdapter restAdapter;

public interface IGibdd {
    @GET("/proxy/check/getSession.php")
    void getSession(Callback<Session> callback);;

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/proxy/check/fines/2.0/client.php")
    void getFines(@Field("regnum") String regnum,
                  @Field("regreg") String regreg,
                  @Field("stsnum") String stsnum,
                  @Field("req") String reqfines,
                  @Field("captchaWord") String captchaWord,
                  Callback<Answer> callback);

}
```

This method requesting captcha, after getting session id

```
private void getCaptcha() {
    final API.IGibdd iGibdd = API.getRestAdapter(this).create(API.IGibdd.class);
    iGibdd.getSession(new Callback<Response>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Response response, Response response2) {
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                getCaptcha();
            } else {
                String cookie = API.loadCookies(CheckFinesActivity.this);
                url = getString(R.string.captcha_url) + cookie + "&" + new Date().getTime();
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("Cookie", cookie);
                DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                        .cacheInMemory(true)
                        .cacheOnDisk(true)
                        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
                        .extraForDownloader(map)
                        .build();
                ImageLoaderConfiguration conf = new  ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(CheckFinesActivity.this)
                        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                        .build();
                ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                imageLoader.init(conf);
                imageLoader.displayImage(url, mCaptchaImage);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

And then, after entering captcha code, i call this method

```
String reqfines = "fines:" + mCarNumber.getText().toString() + ":" + mCarRegion.getText().toString() + ":" + mDocNumber.getText().toString();

            iGibdd.getFines(mCarNumber.getText().toString(),
                    mCarRegion.getText().toString(),
                    mDocNumber.getText().toString(),
                    reqfines,
                    mCaptcha.getText().toString(),
                    new Callback<Answer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Answer s, Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(CheckFinesActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            API.clearSP(CheckFinesActivity.this);
                            getCaptcha();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(CheckFinesActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

UPD2:
Problem is solved. I recreated OkHttp client for a new request and it clears current session

Comment: Could you please share some code? It would be very difficult to locate your problem with only the text descriptions.

Comment: @FelisCatus I'm added some code